# How to calculate the number of days between two dates starting from B.C.5000?

Tags: php

Would like to have this function but with before christ date and taking account into gregorian and julian calendar. I have found solutions for a.d. dates but have not found one for b.c. and my solution requires a lot of manual calculation. Is there an elegant way to do so in php I have missed? An existing built in function I mean.

http://www.timeanddate.com/date/duration.html

Comment: Any reason you can't just add up BC and AD periods to get the full number of days? And also add offsets for different calendars?

Comment: The first thing you may want to do is define what calendar exactly to use. Time keeping wasn't really a very exact science until somewhat recently (and arguably still isn't).

Comment: There is a Calender extension for PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.calendar.php it almost does what you want. it is starting from January 1st, 4713 B.C..

Comment: Will the second date (possibly) also be BC? Or will it always be A.D?

Comment: **shomz** - yes, what kind of function to use for this?

**deceze** - i want to use both. like the timeanddate.com site i mentioned

**kiko** - only for julian calendar...

**leonard** - the second date will always be in a.d.

Comment: On second look, yes, the calender extension is good enough. Thanks a lot, Kiko!

Comment: Why don't you setup a constant with the number of days from 5000BC to year 1 (or whatever the minimum date AD you'll ever use) and work upwards from there? Might save a lot of messing about.

Comment: On third look, the jdtogregorian calendar is not working to expectations. does anyone know where i can get the source code in php for equivalent of jdtogregorian module? i need it in php in uncompiled form (not as php module i mean)

**LeonardChallis** - how does that work? it'll take a lot of arrays... 5000 BC to year 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the original calendar.php function and add in my own solution.

Thanks.